# What is "however" in this sentence referring to?

Tags: grammar, meaning, adverbs

> No definite mass is identified. However, for further evaluation of this patient given his symptoms, an MRI is recommended.

In the above sentence, does the "however" refer back to looking for a mass or forward to further evaluation of the patient's symptoms?

Comment: I have no idea, because I don't know what is meant by "no definite mass is identified" - I suppose it is a medical term?

Comment: @Jasper: Ah, OK. I considered that idea but then rejected it for some reason.

Answer (score 4):

*However* actually *links* the two ideas *no mass* and *further evaluation*, in the sense that although there is no mass found it would still be best to do further evaluation to rule out any danger.

Comment: +1 Definitely the way I read it, and my brother is doing a medical degree, so I am highly exposed to proof reading papers with such wording.  The two sentences could be rearranged in to: "No definite mass was identified, however because of the patient's symptoms, an MRI is recommended."